# Tree: Optional number of subtress

Tags: list, haskell, tree

I have a `data` structure in Haskell that lets me to build a tree.

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int (MultTree b) (MultTree b) (MultTree b) deriving (Show)
```

In that case it is only possible to have `IndexNode` that needs three `MultTree's` as parameters.

How can I make `IndexNode` able to receive 0, 1, 2 or 3 `MultTree's` ?
Implementing `IndexNode` with just different number of parameters does not seem to work.

So in the end I would like to create a tree like that:

```
t2 :: MultTree Int
t2 = IndexNode 3 42 (IndexNode 3 15 (3) (11) (12)) (IndexNode 19 42 (42) (23))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own type containing from zero to three things:

```
data From0To3 a = Zero | One a | Two a a | Three a a a
   deriving (Show)
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int (From0To3 (MultTree b))
   deriving (Show)

t2 :: MultTree Int
t2 = IndexNode 3 42 
     (Two (IndexNode 3 15 
             (Three (DataNode 3) (DataNode 11) (DataNode 12)))
          (IndexNode 19 42
             (Two (DataNode 42) (DataNode 23))))
```

As requested, here's how to dissect such a tree. For instance, the following computes the height of a tree.

```
height :: MultTree a -> Int
height (DataNode _)         = 1
height (IndexNode _ _ Zero) = 1
height (IndexNode _ _ (One t1)) =
   1 + height t1
height (IndexNode _ _ (Two t1 t2)) =
   1 + (height t1 `max` height t2)
height (IndexNode _ _ (Three t1 t2 t3)) =
   1 + (height t1 `max` height t2 `max` height t3)
```

When writing this kind of pattern matching, I strongly recommend to turn on warnings (`-Wall`) so that GHC will tell us if we forget to handle a case.

Comment: Great answer! It would be gread if you explain how to get the subtrees if I would like to do some recursion on an existing tree.

Comment: @jublikon Edited.

Comment: Thank you! What do the _ _ mean ? I understand that operator for Lists but here I am not able to see a syntax

Comment: @jublikon The `_` pattern matches any value and does not give it a name. Compare, e.g., the `t1` pattern, which matches any value and names it `t1`.

Answer (score 2):

Make each one a `Maybe`:

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b
                | IndexNode Int Int (Maybe (MultTree b)) (Maybe (MultTree b)) (Maybe (MultTree b))
```

You still need to provide all the arguments, but a node with only one child might be, for example, `IndexNode 3 6 Nothing (Just (DataNode "hi")) Nothing`.

Alternately, you could simply specify that an `IndexNode` takes a *list* of `MultTree` values, and only allow an `IndexNode` to be created by a smart constructor that checks the number of `MultTree` values being added to it.

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int [MultTree b]

mkIndexNode :: Int -> Int -> [MultTree b] -> MultTree b
mkIndex x y nodes | length nodes > 3 = error "Too many nodes"
                  | otherwise = IndexNode x y nodes
```

You can replace the error with your preferred method of dealing with partial functions. (`Maybe`, `Either`, etc.)